# Enter sudo password prompted in terminal

Tags: command-line, password

In order to install `hplip` to get my printer working again since the update from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 broke it, I opened a terminal according to the instructions of HP, and during the process I was asked to enter the `sudo` password, but I cannot enter it; the keyboard is no longer responding to any key. What can I do to continue installing this program?

Comment: English, please.

Answer (score 1):

- *English*

You keyboard does work, it's only not showing your password on the screen. When asked for your `sudo password`, type you password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

- *French*

Votre clavier fonctionne, il ne montre pas votre mot de passe à l'écran. Quand vous avez demandé votre mot `sudo password`, tapez votre mot de passe et sererz <kbd>Enter</kbd>.